# JAX GPU memory usage even with CPU allocation

Tags: python, gpu, jax

I'm studying memory allocation of JAX to make my code faster and I found GPU memory usage of JAX even though I set it to use only CPU. My little code is:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

jax.config.update('jax_platform_name', 'cpu')

x=jnp.zeros(10)

for i in range(10000000000):
    1+1
```

The for loop is just to see whether this program is using GPU or not.

After this, what I found is it always uses 253MiB of GPU:

> 303028 oh        20   0   29.5g 377844 294168 R 100.0   0.1   0:08.21 python ./test.py

and

[image]

Actually the PID 299133 and 299522 are also using GPU memory with JAX set to use CPU. I'm not sure my actual code is much slower than my c++ code because of this but how can I set it not to use GPU at all?

Comment: Indeed it is the same thing for me. Installing `jax[cpu]` (CPU-only version) fix the problem but I don't know if it is what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a gpu-enabled jaxlib installed, JAX will pre-reserve 90% of the GPU memory on import, unless you specify otherwise via appropriate environment variables. Examples are:

- `XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_PREALLOCATE=false` disables preallocation behavior
- `XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION=.XX` specifies the fraction of memory to preallocate

See [JAX: GPU Memory Allocation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu_memory_allocation.html#gpu-memory-allocation) for more information on this.

If you want to avoid GPU memory allocation altogether, one option is to re-install a CPU-only jaxlib:

```
pip install --force-reinstall "jaxlib[cpu]"
```